# Coroutines inside Recycler Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

for purposes of Room db. I want to run some coroutines inside Recycler View.

Necessary suspend functions are handled as a class parameters:

```
class RecyclerAdapter  (private val  exist : suspend (lastName : String) -> Boolean)
```

And then, when needed I'm using following construction:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   if (exist(dataSet[position].lastName))
       [...]
```

I'm not sure if using the Global Scope is the best practice. I considered using `lifecycleScope` but in Adapter `lifecycleOwner` is not available, handling it as a parameter is not a good practice.

What would you guys suggest?

Answer (score 9):

I think it goes against the single responsibility pattern, as the purpose of an **adapter** is mainly to take care of how the data is laid out.

I would move this information to the list of items, and do the call from the viewmodel, with:

`viewModelScope.launch{}`

than update a `LiveData`/`StateFlow`, observe it from the view, and submit the list to the adapter accordingly

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {}
```

Comment: If you're going to do this, then why not just `launch(Dispatchers.IO)`?

Comment: because inside `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

You can get `LifecycleCoroutineScope` in `onBindViewHolder`.

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: EventViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val coroutineScope =
        holder.itemView.findViewTreeLifecycleOwner()?.lifecycleScope ?: CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
}
```

But as Róbert Nagy said, I don't think it's a good idea to deal directly with business logic inside RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {}`
with `withContext(Dispatchers.Main){}` that helps to update the Recycler View